# How to use union between two different object in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to union data from two different objects. Both these objects have only few fields are common.

Like:

```
class Product
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;  
}

class Category
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public bool IsActive;
}

//Here is my query
(from p in Product
 Select p).Union(from c in Category Select c);
```

Now, if I write a query like the one above, it generates an error:

```
System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload
'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments
```

How can I perform Union operation here?

Comment: What does it mean to you when you union 2 linq queries of 2 different types.. And besides, the code above looks suspicious anyway, because `from p in Product` doesn't make sense.. Product is a class... etc.. Please try to state the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use an anonymous object to include common properties:

```
 var products = Product.Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Name});
 var categories = Category.Select( c=> new {c.Id, c.Name});
 var items = products.Union(categories);
```

Or, use a common base class:

```
class Product
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;  
}

class Category : Product
{
   public bool IsActive;
}

var products = Product.Union(Category.Cast<Product>());
```

(`Product` doesn't have to be the common base class, you could use a third class as the base class)

---

UPDATE: if you want to return a property that doesn't exist in Product (in which case, union is a bit weird), then you should go with an anonymous type:

```
var products = Product.Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Name, IsActive = false});
var categories = Category.Select(c => new {c.Id, c.Name, c.IsActive});
var items = products.Union(categories);
```

Comment: What is there is extra column I want to add and return from category class which is anonymous.

Comment: @sandy what do you mean by "which is anonymous"?  I'm not %100 sure I understand your question, but see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to select common fields (but on some enumerables, not on the types), for example using an anonymous object.

```
var lp = new List<Product>();
var lc = new list<Category>();

var union = lp.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Name})
              .Union(lc.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Name}));
```

Now, I'm not sure of the real sense of doing an Union between a product and a category, but... that's another problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();

var results = (from pro in products select pro.Id)
             .Union (from cat in Category select cat.Id)
```

[Example can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs this but actually want an enumeration of the objects there is a way. As @eren-ersönmez says you can use a base class to union on.

The trick is to remember the base class of everything in .net is object.

So you can do this:

```cs
var all = competitors.Cast<object>().Union(features.Cast<object>())
```

or

```cs
var all = competitors.Select(i => (object)i).Union(features.Select(i => (object)i))
```